# Does Eclipse support Virtual White space?

Tags: eclipse, whitespace

Shortly I will be joining a company that relies heavily on Eclipse for Java development.  For my own development I've used other tools exclusively so I am now getting acquainted with Eclipse before I begin my contract.

One of the features I've grown accustomed to is **Virtual White space**.  This allows you to click anywhere in a given text area and begin typing.  If no white space exists up until your cursor, it will automatically be filled in.  You can see an example of this behavior with the text editor ConTEXT or by turning in on in the Editor settings of Visual Studio.

I can't find an option for it in Eclipse though.  Is there an option I'm missing or will I have to search for a plug-in to enable this feature?

Comment: I don't know if any way to do this in Eclipse, but I'm having trouble seeing why you would want it. Most companies that standardize Eclipse for their IDE also have a standard configuration for the Eclipse formatter, which means you won't need to worry about whitespace very often.

Comment: Virtual White space won't affect the source code, it is simply a matter usability.  I can simply click half-way down a line and start typing rather than tabbing or holding down the space bar.

Comment: When you hit return in the eclipse editor it should automatically add the appropriate indentation.

Comment: Eclipse is a bad choice for anything. I am missing that feature as well. I hope Eclipse will die on some near future day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse does *not* have a plug-in that provides this functionality right now.

As far as I can see from the `TextEditor` class (the basis for almost all Eclipse editors), it will not be an easy task to create such an editor.

You can get the `Point` of the click easily - via `addMouseListener(...)` - but there are no way to add spaces to the document of the editor without it being an separate undoable operation that changes the document. Which must be an additional requirement.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Virtual space only affects the apparent location of the cursor / caret. It does not add spaces to the document unless you start typing at that location - and if the document is read-only, of course that will also fail.