# Enable virtual space in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor

Anyone know if Eclipse supports "virtual space" in the text editor, like VS, Delphi and SQLDeveloper etc etc?

regards!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, can you give an example or something to help clarify this?

Comment: It means that you can move the cursor around, anywhere in the source file, even after the end-of-line marker.

Comment: [this answer][1] says no.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203360/does-eclipse-support-virtual-white-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This very old Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21000) shows that it's not provided.